# List keep on printing even when 0 was entered by the user

Tags: python, python-2.7, input, type-conversion

```
end = False
numbers = []
while not end:
 i =(raw_input(" Enter the number(0 to end the input)")) 
 if i ==0:
  end = True
 else:
  numbers.append(i)
 print numbers
```

List does not exit even when the input by the user entered is 0

Answer (score 3):

you getting your as a string instead number..

try to convert it into integer or get it as an integer

try this,

```
if int(i) == 0
```

or get your input as ,

```
i =(input(" Enter the number(0 to end the input)"))
```